# What does 'aligned' mean, for structs in c?

Tags: c#, c, struct, pinvoke

I'm strugling a bit writing some glue code between a c api and a .net application. In order to write the C# struct, I need to figure out what is actually going on on the c side here.

```
typedef struct CommonDialogBaseParam {
    size_t size;
    uint8_t reserved[36];
    uint32_t magic;
} CommonDialogBaseParam __attribute__ ((__aligned__(8)));

// Somewhere else
#define __attribute__(x)
```

I'm tempted to write the C# equivalent as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct CommonDialogBaseParam {
    public ulong size;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=36)]
    public string reserved;
    public uint magic;
}
```

Needless to say... I don't really need proper access to either 'reserved' or 'magic' on the C# side, but I need the members to be preserved properly.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm worried that __aligned__(8) changes the memory layout of the struct, so that I have to make equivalent changes on the C# side, but I don't know what aligned means in this case.

Comment: Well, `__attribute__` is defined to nothing, so nothing is happening there ;-). Could be a gcc define.

Comment: I don't know how relevant [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms384329(v=vs.71).aspx) is (.NET 2003), but they define `#pragma pack(push, 8)` for the C struct and `[StructLayout(LayoutKind::Sequential, Pack=8)]` on the C# side.

Comment: Sidenote: `size_t` is unsigned type.

Comment: @user694733 True, and not at all guaranteed to have (u)int size.

Comment: Yes, I will have to double check why my 'size' is int, that might be a simple mistake on my part. I think the Pack attribute will deal with the other issue. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It's probably safe to assume this is MS Windows code, so `size_t` will be a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: the size_t's on my system should be ulong... it was a mistake an not the core of the question, so I've changed the 'size' in the question to be ulong.

Comment: No, `size_t` is not `ulong`. It is `UIntPtr`. It is pointer sized.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Referring (64bit)-Windows: ["*`size_t`, `time_t`, and `ptrdiff_t` are 64-bit values on 64-bit Windows operating systems.*"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2e7499.aspx)

Comment: @alk Oops, yes. I should have checked before posting. Sorry for the noise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a GCC attribute that specifies the minimum alignment of the structure to be 8 bytes. The documentation can be found here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes

This influences allocation of these structs, but it does not impact the offsets of the struct itself. However, it does mean that the native structure may have extra padding after the final member.

There is no equivalent to this in C#, and depending on what the native code does with the struct you may encounter problems. The structure might be misaligned if allocated by your C# code, but that would only affect performance rather than correctness. If the native code makes a copy of the struct, then it will attempt to read any padding at the end of the struct. And conceivably that could lead to an access violation. My guess would be that the heap allocator used by p/invoke will allocate memory in chunks with block size of at least 8, so you'd likely get away with this. But I doubt you could ever rely on that.

Leaving this padding aside, I would translate your struct like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CommonDialogBaseParam {
    public UIntPtr size;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=36)]
    public byte[] reserved;
    public uint magic;
}
```

Note that I have mapped `size_t` to `UIntPtr`, an unsigned pointer sized value. And personally I prefer to see a `byte[]` for the `reserved` field. This feels more true to the C code, so far as I can tell.

If you want to be sure that you structure will be big enough then you could add an extra field at the end:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CommonDialogBaseParam {
    public UIntPtr size;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=36)]
    public byte[] reserved;
    public uint magic;
    private uint padding;
}
```

Since none of the types contained in this struct have a size greater than 8, then you could abuse the `Pack` option of `StructLayout` to achieve the desired effect:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
public struct CommonDialogBaseParam {
    public UIntPtr size;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=36)]
    public byte[] reserved;
    public uint magic;
}
```

But be careful with this. The native code aligns the struct. The C# declaration above aligns the struct, and specifies alignment of its members. It so happens here that this does not impact the member alignment, but that would not always be the case.

All in all, a little unsatisfactory.

Comment: Hmm... wouldn't 'magic' be pushed 4 bytes forward, so that it would start on an 8-byte boundary?

Comment: No it would not. The documentation I linked to doesn't suggest that.

Comment: Wouldn't the 8 byte alignment affect the size of the structure on 32-bit Windows? I.e. wouldn't the C version of the struct have 4 bytes of hidden padding at the end to round it up from size 44 to size 48?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Using `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]` as suggested in earlier comments would appear to fix that.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, for this particular type, but not universally. `Pack` impacts alignment of the structure and its members. The C code in the question only specifies alignment of the structure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, `Pack=8` would be bad if any members aligned to 16 byte boundaries or larger by default.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The explicit `padding` member in your 2nd example would be bad on 64-bit Windows, since it would make the C# struct larger than the C struct in that case.

Comment: That would matter if you were allocating arrays. Everything is a compromise here.